# ERROR: "Please install sqlite3 package manually" when I execute "sequelize db:migrate"

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, database-migration, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to create a sample app, using this article:

https://arjunphp.com/restful-api-using-async-await-node-express-sequelize/

But when a try to execute database migration with sequenze-cli on sqlite, a have always the same error:

```
C:\WORKING\todo\todos-manager>sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.16.0, CLI: 5.5.0, ORM: 5.8.12]

Loaded configuration file "config\config.json".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: Please install sqlite3 package manually
```

I've already tried to rebuild, with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to install `sqlite3` package additionally, as said in the error message. Run `npm install sqlite3 --save`.

Comment: Already done, no success!

Comment: Strange. Have you tried completely removing the `node_modules` directory and running fresh `npm install`?

Comment: @AnnaPohorielova: yes!

Answer (score 1):

The error does not occur if I use the statement:

```
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

instead of

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

and migration completes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

First install sequelize-cli globally

`sudo npm install -g sequelize-cli`

Then use the following command to execute migrations.

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case both:
`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`
and
`sequelize db:migrate`
didn't work.
I don't know if its a bad practice but only global installation:
 `npm i -g sqlite3`
 solve the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried with Node10.x. Your installed sqlite3 version might not be matching with Node-version, so please switch your version to Node8.x or 9.x.

Use NVM to switch between versions and try avoid installing packages globally.

Comment: thanks for the answers, can you show which commands you ran?

Comment: Install nvm and type this command : 
nvm install 8.

Node8 version will get installed, then do nvm list which will show the list of node versions installed in your system.
To use specific version, do nvm use <version>.

After switching to Node8 version , I did npm install and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case sqllite3 was not installed due to node version mismatch . I switched my node version to  v9.11.1 and the error is gone afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Setting [`unsafe-perm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#unsafe-perm) worked for me:

`npm i --unsafe-perm`

Answer (score 0):

If your down here without a fix, it might be possible you have npm postinstall scripts disabled like me. For me the fix was to:

```sh
cd project
cd node_modules/sqlite3
npm install
cd ../../
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

And now it works

Answer (score 0):

If you have still not been able to get it to work at this stage then run this in the project folder:

```
npm update

npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

Please install sqlite3 node module globally, it will fix the problem

```
npm i -g sqlite3
```